# How to manipulate objective-C global objects?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object

So far I've defined my class mybeacon, extension of ESTBeacon, set a property, "counter" in this case. I would like to have "counter" as a global variable, did I do it in the right way with property? In my ViewController I've set an NSMutableArray property called "beaconsArray", which represents all beacons, which were detected by Application.

When I'm ranging beacons, I'm getting an array of ESTBeacon objects. Now I dont know am I doing it in the right way, but Im trying to check wether beacon is in beaconsArray array if not put it into array, otherwise if its already there just increase "counter" property..

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
    for (ESTBeacon* beacon in beacons)
    {

        if (![self.beaconsArray containsObject:beacon ]) {
            NSString *msg = [self get_message:[beacon.major unsignedShortValue]];
            UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
            notification.alertBody = msg;
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
            NSString *url = [self mysql_process:[beacon.major unsignedShortValue]];
            [webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url]]];
            //here convert object ESTBeacon into object mybeacon which has additional property and put the object into my array, which can grow only here.
        } else if ([self.beaconsArray containsObject:beacon ]) { 
//just increase a property counter by 1 and do something more or do nothing at all.

}





    }
    [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off asking about what you're trying to achieve as a 'global' variable isn't a good plan (and you don't show how you define or use it so how can we tell if it will work)

Comment: I just want to put ESTBeacon object as a mybeacon object(with new property) into an array, so that mybeacon has additional property counter.

Answer (score 0):

use `NSUserDefaults` to store global variables which can be accessed from anywhere throughout your application.

NSUserDefaults Tutorial: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039